# В C# windows form преобразование типа string в double и наоборот

Tags: c#, winforms

Как сделать что бы из `textbox` значения перевести в тип `double` `и` что бы читалась в числе и точка и запятая?И как вывести в `label` тип double?

И нужно в расчетах (обычных математических формулах) сделать, чтобы ответы округлялись до `0.00` и `0.000`?

Я начинаю программировать и поэтому такие вопросы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

параметр checkBox.text  принимаеn строку. А значит нужно перевести ваше значение с типом double  в строку.
Для этого используйте на вашей переменной метод ToString();

```
double doubleValue = 0.2;
string someStringValue = "";
someStringValue  = doubleValue.ToString();
```

Что бы перевести из строки в doublе или другой тип вам нужно использовать

```
double.Parse(string value);
```

К примеру:

```
string someStringValue = "0.2";
double someDoubleValue = double.Parse(someStringValue);
```

Подобным образом можно парсить и другие типы. К примеру:

```
int integerValue = int.Parse(someValue);
float floatValue = float.Parse(someValue);
```

Но может возникнуть проблема и ваша программа упадет на этапе выполнения если входные данные будет невозможно конвертировать.
За этим нужно следить. Как вариант можно использовать к примеру

```
double doubleValue;
double.TryParse("some string", out doubleValue);
```

в этом случае если входная строка имела верный формат  этот метод вернет вам тру и поместит в значение doubleValue данные. Если же нет, то метод вернет вам фолс
И вот вам сразу ссылка на округление. там вы сможете детальнее  его разобрать 
https://aakinshin.net/ru/posts/cheatsheet-rounding/

что бы вывести что то в lable  можете использовать

```
someLable.Text = "необходимые данные";
```

Если все же будет падать при конвертировании со строки в double  то как вариант можно подключить

```
using System.Globalization;
```

и передать

```
double.Parse("2.2",new NumberFormatInfo())
```

Comment: 1. А пустую строку зачем присваивал? 2. Про культуру ни слова. 3. В out-переменную нельзя ничего не записать - там будет 0.

Comment: согласен, в строку можно было ничего не присваивать.

Answer (score 0):

1. Получаем значение введенное в TextBox через свойство text, переводим в double и если введена точка, мы ее заменяем на запятую методом Replace.

`double double1 = double.Parse(textBox1.Text.Replace(',', '.'), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

2. В lable выводим так же через свойство Text. Что бы число перевести в строку, используем метод ToString.

`label1.Text = double1.ToString();`

3. Что бы округлить до нужного количества знаков, используем перегрузки метода ToString. Надо два знака после запятой, пишите `double1.ToString("#.##")`, если три `double1.ToString("#.###")`

`label1.Text = double1.ToString("#.###");`

Comment: Не трожь точку.

Comment: double.Parse(textBox1.Text.Replace('.', ',')) а не накрячится ли без указания культуры?

Comment: @Qwertiy, без `Replace('.', ',')` он выдаст исключение.

Comment: @WebMorda, и с ним - тоже. По крайней мере, у меня. И ещё у половины мира.

Comment: @yolosora, смотря какой текст будет. Не должен, если правильно писать.

Comment: @Qwertiy, исправил, теперь должно работать.

Comment: @WebMorda, а чем не устраивает нормальный вариант с текущей культурой?

Answer (score 0):

```
        //Из string в double (num - количество знаков после запятой)
        private double? ToDouble(string str,int num = 2)
        {
            string[] mass = str.Split(new Char[] { ',','.' });
            if (mass.Length > 2) return null;
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
            double result;
            Double.TryParse($"{mass[0]}.{mass[1]}", out result);
            result = Math.Round(result, num,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Это вообще жесть. Мало того, что в настройках можно поставить не только точку и запятую, так ты ещё и настройки всего исполняемого топока портишь этой функцией.